# Is there any way to generate JMeter script on the fly for the existing Test automation script

Tags: jmeter

I am just wondering is there any way or possible to generate JMeter script on the fly for the existing test automation script.
Basically the idea is to use the same Test automation script let's say Test automation script was created using selenium for the performance testing too using JMeter.

Any ideas or thoughts?

-Raj

Thanks,
Rajani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to record your Selenium test.

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [Configure your Selenium scripts to use JMeter as a proxy](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)
3. Start the test - JMeter will be recording.

This way you will get test "skeleton" however you will still need to handle dynamic parameters. To avoid this step you can try out an alternative recording solution, it is capable of exporting JMeter tests in "SmartJMX" mode with automated correlation applied. See [How to Convert Selenium Scripts into the JMX](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) article for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! Excellent!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware to achieve this is to record the selenium run and then save the jmeter script.
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733979-Recording-a-user-session-with-the-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

You can run the JMeter stuff programmatically using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/).

Using it, you can write your own test harness that creates the test items on the fly, then build the test plan out of them, and run it.
Or loads existing plan "template", access & alter the test elements in it, then, again run it.

Though that is kinda tricky part, so first ask yourself (then share with us here) what *exactly* do you need it for, and then try to consider the possibility to implement that using JMeter scripting components.

Basically, in your case, you can call the Selenium stuff in the JSR223/Beanshell components through [Selenium API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/).

And moreover, [there exist a plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) to do the things with Selenium stuff.

PS Although the very idea of using something all-purpose "to rule 'em all" usually doesn't pay off, 'cause the effort needed to maintain that "universality" often overcome the one smartly made for separate functional/load suites.

Comment: Hi  Yuri,Yes I am clear what I am looking for as clearly mentioned in the thread.We are trying to look possible ways to use single script for functional automation as well as for the performance testing for the same test case. Any ways thanks, and I will look into.-Rajani